# Is there any way to install an Unreal Engine project in Xcode iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, unreal-engine5

Is there any way to package/install/run our game in an Xcode iPhone/iPad Simulator?

I’m working on a Silicon (arm64) Mac, so you would think it’s possible. Using Ventura, UE 5.1.1, and Xcode 14.

Trying to drag either `ipa` or `app` onto simulator does not work.

And not seeing any Simulators in the UE **Platforms** menu.

This is mainly for generating screenshots in various sizes for App Store submission…

Thanks!